# Sudden error while running the npm react-native run-android. Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I suddenly got an error saying Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Problems reading data from Binary store in C:\Users\prabh\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle13962421950392783403.bin offset 114265 exists? true
I think this error is related to react native firebase. I am using react-native-firebase/app,firebase/auth,firebase/messaging packages. I am using these packages from long time but  never faced an issue before. The only thing I did hours before getting this error is npm audit fix to fix some vulnerabulities. Anyone got a similar error?

build.gradle dependencies:

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0' //For Notifications
implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0' // <-- add this; newer versions should work too
implementation project(':react-native-fs') //addes Manually compile project
implementation project(':react-native-get-real-path')
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
// For animated GIF support
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
// For WebP support, including animated WebP
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'
```

Comment: did u try in android studio, File-> Invalidate Cache and restart -> Invalidate and restart

Comment: No that didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked for me on Windows 10 and Android. I didn't try on Mac or Linux.
I saw that from https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8489 @jack7891
Thank you jack.
android/build.gradle
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'` to classpath `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'`

android/app/build.gradle
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'` to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2'`

package.json

```
 "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.1.2",
 "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.1.2",
 "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^11.1.2",
 "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^11.1.2",
 "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.1.2",
 "react-native-push-notification": "^7.2.3",
```

to

```
 "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0",
 "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.5.0",
 "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^11.5.0",
 "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^11.5.0",
 "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0",
 "react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.1",
```

Then run `npm install` or `yarn install`

After that, go to android project folder and run:

```
./gradlew.bat clean
```

Finally, you can go to project folder and run `npx react-native run-android`